# Best way to store unroasted/raw coffee?

Tags: beans, storage

I'm using green coffee and would like to know how to keep the beans to protect from getting bad (mold). I try to keep them safe and to be all time ready for roasting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a few different varieties of green beans that I have stored in freezer style plastic bags for going on 1+ year now and there is no mold present.  I keep them stored at room temperate with as much air as possible removed from the bag.  I roast a few batches a year and always get the same results out of my beans regardless of how long they have been stored.

Comment: As a further reference: The same recommendation (sealed plastic bags, in the dark, at room temperature) is listed [at The Coffee FAQ](http://www.thecoffeefaq.com/5homeroasting.html#storinggreen). They also recommend cloth/mesh bags in a cool, dry, dark location, but this is probably impractical for most "home" operations. @jjwr: welcome to [coffee.se]!

Comment: My green bean supplier ships them to me in sealed ziplock style bags.  I store them in a dark cupboard where they are also presumably kept safe from moisture and temperature fluctuations.  Green coffee will keep for roughly a year, generally far longer than a home roaster needs to cycle through a supply (I order new beans at least every other month).

Answer (score 2):

Green coffee storage should be done similarly to roasted.
1-free of contact with oxygen 
2-cool
3-away from light

This is according to National Coffee Assoc.
http://www.ncausa.org/About-Coffee/How-to-Store-Coffee

I pre-weigh my beans to the exact amount weight that I will need for my roast. (i.e. 100g) and  pack it in individual bags. then use a machine that removes all the air and seals the bags. I forget it's name but the are inexpensive and do good jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Double zipper Ziplock bags in a dry place away from light works for me.

Comment: Welcome to [coffee.se]. Your answer was short and too the point, but it was very similar to the previous answer from jjwr. Do you have anything more to add -- some references, or other things you have tried like refrigerating or freezing?

Comment: An explanation as to why your suggestion works would also be a good improvement to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unroasted/green coffee stores very, very well.  Keep them in containers or sealable plastic bags in a place that is pretty fairly temperature stable, dark and not particularly humid, and you should be fine.  I keep mine in the cupboard over the fridge.  They can be kept for months with minimal effort going towards storage with no impact on their after-roasted quality.